# Python3 issue using cookiejar and urllib.request

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, urllib

I am trying to get data from a B2B site regarding some products.

I wrote a python script to do a search on that platform (it's wordpress platform) using cookiejar and urllib.request. This is working fine, I do get the products url but when I am trying to load a specific product its like the cookie not working anymore.

```py
import os, http.cookiejar, urllib.request
# ls is a list with all the products SKU
for v in ls:
    cj = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
    cj.load(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".netscape", "path\\to\\cookieFile\\cookies.txt"))
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    url = "https://b2b.platform.com/?s="
    r = opener.open(url+v)
```

So far this part is working fine. After that there is a regex to find the URL of the product and then I am trying to load that URL by using this code

```py
cj = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
cj.load(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".netscape", "path\\to\\cookieFile\\cookies.txt"))
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open(productURL)
```

Though the first part searching for the product URL is working as expected the second part where I am trying to load the specific URL it is like it's not reading the cookie at all. The result of the HTML is the login page.
Moreover, if I use

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt "productURL" -o product.html
```

This is working as it should